# Need assistance with for loop to count continuous green candles after a crossover, please assist

Tags: loops, conditional-statements

redcnd = close<open

```
for i = 1 to barsince(crossma)
```

count number of blocks of continuous or single red candle and insert the count on top of the respective red

same thing for green block

I tried many things but failed every time, need expert's help

block[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ruc5v.png)

I tried many things but failed every time, need expert's help

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and a tag for the programming language you are using

Comment: can we number the blocks of green and red candles, like in the screenshot

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. The code you've shared does not use any blocks or candles, and I have no clue what these two terms could refer to

Comment: for i=0 to barsince(condition)
if close>open